# How do i change only the Copyright of my Prestashop page?

Tags: themes, smarty, prestashop, footer

I couldn't find anything about changing my Copyright of the footer. That little part that says: "**A SHOP** © 2014. All Rights Reserved."

I just need to change that little part having it to say "**B-divine** © 2014. All Rights Reserved."

I looked at "modules" -> "positions" at the footer part. No module installed. Alright, then looked at the folders where my site is hosted. Looked up various .tps files and so on, but couldn't find the right one.

The question is not connected with `Powered by PrestaShop`which is originally in Block CMS.

Answer (score 2):

I just found it! If anyone is looking for that solution:

Look up the `footer.tpl` file at about line 55

```
file-path: \themes\YOUR_THEME\footer.tpl
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, wich template are you using?

Usually the "Developed using PrestaShop" copyright information can be deactivated in the CMS Configuration module, if thats what you are trying to change.

Answer (score 0):

At modules, blockcms, open blockcms.tpl in the line 101,102,103 is where you can change your copyright and write yours, first at the modules and after at the theme modules